# Is there any TUI application for commandline for command rsync?

Tags: rsync, tui

I use rsync now from the command line between two servers to transfer files. Is there a **command line TUI application** for rsync or something else which does the same?

Common use cases is to exclude multiple folders from within the folder which is being transferred. It would be usefull to that with some sort of TUI. Even better would be to see the folder size along with it.

Edit: the application should run in a CLI anointment. I am looking for a TUI like Midnight Commander or NCDU.

Edit2: apparently a GUI for CLI is called a TUI, (a Text-based user interface). Didn't know that. Edited the question.

Comment: @User24601 Thanks for your reply, but did you actually read the question? :P

Comment: @user68186 I mean an actual interface without the need to type commands. But it must work on servers without and X (window) server. An interface something like midnight commander or ncdu.

Comment: So that's not a GUI. GUI runs on X display by definition. So my answer about `grsync` is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was called a TUI. I will edit!

Answer (score 1):

I use [grsync](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync/), it's a simple GUI that supports most of "basic" rsync parameters, however for include/exclude parameters, in this tool you have to add them manually. It does not support GUI selection of directories to include/exclude.

Edit: I just understood from your comments that you want a TUI application, not GUI. I just found a video demonstrating some TUI application for rsync, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrBUZ2g5_O4 . I don't know this app, so I can't provide any more information about it. There's a Github link in the Youtube video description: https://github.com/gotbletu/shownotes/blob/master/vifm_rsync_frontend.md

Comment: I must run in a CLI environment. Since the server doesn't have X server. That's why I asked for a CLI GUI (for the lack of a better word).

Comment: It's called TUI (or "ncurses", from the name of a library such applications usually use), as @user68186 noted above. I just found a video demonstrating some TUI app for rsync, check my edited answer.

Comment: It would be great if you could mention the TUI app by name and how to install it, rather than a link to YouTube. Links go dead all the time. That's why at Ask Ubuntu a link only answer is not considered a good answer. By the same logic you should mention how to install `grsync`. For example, what command to enter in the terminal or how to look for it in the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: I don't know this app, I never used it. I just found the Youtube video NOW. So that's all I know. There's a Github link in the Youtube video description.